# Easy way to preview 120 fps footage at 30 fps?

Tags: slowmotion

I recently got a Nikon Z7 and I've been playing with its ability to shoot 120 fps at 1080p and then make slow-motion 30fps (or even 24 fps) videos from it.   A 120 fps video can be used to generate a slower-fps video using Premiere Pro or even ffmpeg if you don't dialing your Wayback machine to 1983 and typing in a command line.

But if I have a bunch of 120 fps videos and I want to select the one that looks best, I just want to **VIEW** them at a slower playback speed.
Is there any way to do that either in-camera or with some simple Windows app?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view at slower playback speed, would videoLan help?

```
Menu->Playback->Speed->Slower
```

then check if the speed at 0.25x is it what you want.